Maintaining type correlation between tuple of arguments passed to function depending on generic parameter that is union
I want to fix TypeScript issue when I have a generic function that takes arguments that depends on each other (so they depend on generic) and after that I pass these arguments to the function inside my generic function. That function takes pair of arguments (screen and value). Here is the example:
Playground: https://tsplay.dev/mLV2ew
// --- Start Types here is from third party that I cannot change ---
export type ParamListBase = Record<string, object | undefined>;

type ScreenParamsPair<
  ParamList extends ParamListBase,
  RouteName extends keyof ParamList,
> = {
  // First we use a mapped type to get an union of screen & params pairs
  // Then we pick the pair which matches the RouteName
  // Mapped type is used instead of just ParamList[RouteName]
  // Otherwise it'll result in union of all params leading to incorrect types
  [Screen in keyof ParamList]: undefined extends ParamList[Screen] // Params are either undefined or a union with undefined
    ?
      | [screen: Screen] // if the params are optional, we don't have to provide it
      | [screen: Screen, params: ParamList[Screen]]
    : [screen: Screen, params: ParamList[Screen]];
}[RouteName];

type NavigationHelpersCommon<
  ParamList extends ParamListBase,
> = {
  navigate<RouteName extends keyof ParamList>(
    ...args: ScreenParamsPair<ParamList, RouteName>
  ): void;
}

type NavigationProp<ParamList extends {}> = NavigationHelpersCommon<ParamList>

function useNavigation<T = NavigationHelpersCommon<{}>>(): T {
  return {} as T;
}
// --- End Types here is from third party that I cannot change ---

type Obj1 = {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
  field3: string;
}
type Obj2 = {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
}
type Obj3 = {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
  field3: `#${string}`
}

export type AppStackParamList = {
  Screen1: { value: string | null };
  Screen2: { value: Obj1 | null };
  Screen3: { value: Obj2 | null };
  Screen4: { value: Obj3 | null };
}

type ScreenValueMap = {
  'Screen1': 'string',
  'Screen2': { field1: '213', field2: '123', field3: '512' },
  'Screen3': { field1: '213', field2: '123' },
}

type Props<T extends keyof ScreenValueMap> = {
  screen: T,
  value: ScreenValueMap[T]
}

const genericFunction = <T extends keyof ScreenValueMap>({ screen, value }: Props<T>) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProp<AppStackParamList>>();
  navigation.navigate(screen, { value }); // Error here

  navigation.navigate(screen, { value: null })
}

This is error that I see:
Argument of type '[keyof ScreenValueMap, { value: "string" | { field1: "213"; field2: "123"; field3: "512"; } | { field1: "213"; field2: "123"; }; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ScreenParamsPair<AppStackParamList, keyof AppStackParamList>'.
  Type '[keyof ScreenValueMap, { value: "string" | { field1: "213"; field2: "123"; field3: "512"; } | { field1: "213"; field2: "123"; }; }]' is not assignable to type '[screen: "Screen1", params: { value: string | null; }] | [screen: "Screen2", params: { value: Obj1 | null; }] | [screen: "Screen3", params: { value: Obj2 | null; }]'.
    Type '[keyof ScreenValueMap, { value: "string" | { field1: "213"; field2: "123"; field3: "512"; } | { field1: "213"; field2: "123"; }; }]' is not assignable to type '[screen: "Screen3", params: { value: Obj2 | null; }]'.
      Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
        Type 'keyof ScreenValueMap' is not assignable to type '"Screen3"'.
          Type '"Screen1"' is not assignable to type '"Screen3"'.(2345)

I've simplified example to easier to read it, but problem is the same.
In cases where generic is union, it looks like Typescript loose correlation between pair screen - value, so when I pass arguments to navigate​ function, I end up with a separate union type for the screen and a separate union type for the values instead of a union of pairs screen - value. I read some issues about "correlated union type" but I can't understand how to fix this issue. Even typecasts (except any) is not helping here, but I want to have some typesafety, so any is not suitable for me.

This is fairly confusing code, especially the conditional undefined extends parts, and the naming conventions. I'm trying to fight my way through it to see what you're doing but it's not obvious. Could you simplify it further, or comment it?

@jcalz I added a comment from library sources, this part of the code I can't control, maybe if we figure it out, we can create an issue for that lib. In my case I try to create a generic with some subset of the screens (only for Screen1,2,3) I can navigate to and corresponding parameters. ScreenValueMap is just an example of data that I added to simplify the original code. In reality, I pass one another parameter that resolves to the screen name and value that resolves inside the function depending on the generic argument, but the error is still the same as in the example.

The code is still too confusing for me to follow, sorry. Not the library code, which I understand (but could still be simplified for the example), but what you're trying to do with it. I don't understand why or how or if ScreenValueMap relates to AppStackParamList. I'm asking you to either simplify it or clarify it with text in the question. Maybe there's some way to use ms/TS#47109 to make it work, but if I don't understand what's going on then I can't really help.

(see prev comment) I can strip it way down and build it back up to this playground link, which is the basic ms/TS#47109 technique. But I get stuck at ScreenValueMap/AppStackParamList and how they are related.

@jcalz I've updated a bit with clarification, please take a look: https://tsplay.dev/wQQYYw

I don't know, it's not making much sense to me. I'll go to sleep and take another look tomorrow.

Had a full night's sleep, looked again, it's still not meaning much for me. I think I'm going to just disengage. Sorry I couldn't help.

first, shouldnt
type Props<T extends keyof ScreenValueMap> = {
  screen: T,
  value: ScreenValueMap[T]
}

be
type Props<T extends keyof ScreenValueMap> = {
  screen: T,
  value: AppStackParamList[T]
}

?
I dont have clear idea on how to fix this but my guess is navigation.navigate does not have enough generics for your case
see below example
type O = {
    x:1
    y:2
}
// your case
// your code
const a=<T extends keyof O>(v:T,w:O[T])=>{
  b(v,w) // error!
}
// library code
const b = <T extends keyof O>(...arg:{[k in keyof O]:[k, O[k]]}[T])=>{
}

// fixed!
// your modified code
const a1=<T extends keyof U, U extends O>(v:T,w:U[T])=>{
  b1(v,w) // no error
}
// library modified code
const b1 = <T extends keyof U, U extends O>(...arg:{[k in keyof U]:[k, U[k]]}[T])=>{
}

playground
so seem like it is fixable but we have to modify 3rd party's type

ScreenValueMap[T] is right for the value, it's just a subset of all variants for navigation, it's intended. About library modified code, you can check in the playground, the code you provided as a replacement for navigate is still failing

If we tweak the type of props like to make T distributive:
type Props<T extends keyof ScreenValueMap> = T extends T
  ? {
      screen: T;
      value: ScreenValueMap[T];
    }
  : never;

We can modify the generic function like so to help TS know what the types are.
const genericFunction = <T extends keyof ScreenValueMap>({
  screen,
  value,
}: Props<T>) => {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation<NavigationProp<AppStackParamList>>();
  if (screen === "Screen1") {
    navigate(screen, { value });
    return;
  }
  if (screen === "Screen2") {
    navigate(screen, { value });
    return;
  }
  if (screen === "Screen3") {
    navigate(screen, { value });
    return
  }
};

Which should work with no errors.  Until we check the value of screen the value prop is an undiscriminated union of possible values.
